# How to use data filtering in Angular component in case of an array of nested objects?

Tags: angular

I'd like to create an instant search function based on this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvASSPQMrUE/) tutorial video for my project. You can find the written version [here](https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2018/05/data-filter-in-angular-component.html).

Everything works fine with the following JSON structure (used by the same tutorial series):

```
[
 0: {
  id: 123,
  firstName: "Jon",
  lastName: "Doe",
  ...
 },
 1: {
  id: 321,
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Someone",
  ...
 }
]
```

However I need to use the following JSON structure in my project and I cannot modify it (fetched through REST API):

```
[
 0: {
  employee: {
    id: 123,
    firstName: "Jon",
    lastName: "Doe",
    ...
  },
  someOtherObject: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    ...
  },
  anotherObject: {
    ...
  }  
 },
 1: {
   employee: {
    id: 321,
    firstName: "Tom",
    lastName: "Someone",
    ...
  },
  someOtherObject: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
  },
  anotherObject: {
    ...
  }  
 },
]
```

The search function doesn't work with the above JSON structure.

I'd like to search in most of the nested objects with the same instant search experience.

Update:

The employee.component.ts looks like the same as the [linked](https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2018/05/data-filter-in-angular-component.html) guide.

The employee.ts looks like this:

```
export class Document {
    _id: string;
    _rev: string;
    employee: any[];
    otherArray: any[];
    anotherArray: any[];
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of filteredEmployees">
    {{ employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName }}
</div>
```

Comment: what's the question? what have you tried?

Comment: please show more code. we can't help you figure it out if we don't know what you have now.

Comment: I've added some code samples. But basically everything looks the same as the linked written guide, expect the fetched JSON file.

Comment: Okay, assuming you copied the code from that example, then in `filteredEmployees()` method you need to make sure you are accessing the right key for your data structure. In the example they access `employee.name`, you need to access `employee.employee.name` to account for nesting. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe

In combination with a text input, some model binding and a pipe, you should be able to achieve what I think you're after.

In the HTML

```
<input id="filter_input" type="text" [value]="filterBy" placeholder="Filter by {{filterOnText}}" (input)="filterBy = $event.target.value">

<div *ngFor="let employee of filteredEmployees | filter:filterOnKey:filterBy ">
    {{ employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName }}
</div>
```

then in the Component

```
filterOnText: string;
filterOnKey: string;
filterBy = '';
```

then the Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

/*____________________________________________________________
* usage: *ngFor="let license of licenses  | filter:'Name':filterBy;
* 'Name' is the name of the column in list.
* filterBy obtained from input box
*_____________________________________________________________
*/
transform(items: any, property: any, term: any): any {
    if (!term) {
        return items;
    }

    const result = items.filter(function (item) {           

            if (item[property] === null) {
                return items;
            }
            if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        if (result.length === 0) {
            return [-1];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```